# how to apply negation in OWL property chaining

Tags: owl, semantic-web, protege

I'm learning Semantic web and creating a simple ontology as shown below part of the learning process. Goal is to see if the reasoner can infer suggestedSkill (dotted line below)

[image]

Here, relatedTo is

- transitive
- symmetric

Here are a couple of instances

[image]

because of the transitive & symmetric characteristics, the way the reasoner infers is below

[image]

I've circled the problem above, how to model this correctly?

Appreciate any pointers.

Comment: In your ontology, you state that react.js is unrelated to angular.js, but is that correct for your model? If so, they cannot both be related to javascript, because of the transitive characteristic. I think either your properties should not be transitive/symmetric, or the unrelated association might be misplaced.